# Java HashMap<int[], Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, implementation, treemap

I want to map an array to an `ArrayList` such that two arrays mapped to the same thing if they are identical.

This outputs `null`:

```java
HashMap<int[], Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new int[1], 0);
System.out.println(map.get(new int[1]));
```

And I want the output to be `0`. Is there an easy way to do this? Should I use `TreeMap`? How do I do this in `TreeMap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `TreeMap` works, if you pass in a Comparator instance that can be used with arrays. Luckily the standard library already has a method you can use [`Arrays.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-int:A-int:A-):

```java
TreeMap<int[], Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(Arrays::compare);
map.put(new int[1], 1);
System.out.println(map.get(new int[1])); // output: 1
```

That said, using a mutable object such as an array as the map key is not a very good idea. If you accidentally change an array used as a key, the map will stop working as expected.

The reason why `HashMap` will not work is because arrays don't implement a `hashCode` or `equals` method based on the array contents. They are based on the object identity instead.

---

[`Arrays.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-int:A-int:A-) was added in *Java 9*. For *Java 8* you'll need to write the `Comparator` yourself. Here is one option:

```java
Comparator<int[]> arrayComparator = (a, b) -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++) {
        int compare = Integer.compare(a[i], b[i]);
        if (compare != 0) return compare;
    }
    return Integer.compare(a.length, b.length);
};
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to add a possible alternative implementation of Arrays.compare for Java 8

Comment: Does that work for Java 7 and under?

Comment: so how do I get my Java 8 program to work? Where do I place this comparator?

Comment: For Java 7, you would have to rewrite `arrayComparator` as a class that implements the `Comparator` interface because Java 7 lacks the lambda expression feature. For Java 6 you would have to make even more changes, for Java 5 even more still. But do note that Java 8 came out over 6 years ago

Comment: `new TreeMap<>(arrayComparator)`